# pandas dataframe style - how to colormap each row individually (not whole together)

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, pandas-styles

I have a dataframe (`df`) like this, using color map for styling:

```
#create random 30 x 30 frame
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, (5, 20)))

df.style.background_gradient(cmap='RdYlGn_r')
```

[image]

The above code colors the dataframe over all the numbers (5 x 20 cells - smaller numbers in green, bigger numbers in red).

How can I color the small to big for each row considered individually (NOT as a whole group of 5 x 20 cells) i.e. as a 1 row x 20 cols for row 0 to 4 considered separately.

===

Example the following 2 examples for above `df`, highlights **medians by row and column individually** using apply. How can I color each row as above example for small to big numbrs.

```
def highlight_max(s):
    '''
    highlight the maximum in a Series yellow.
    '''
    is_max = s == s.max()
    return ['background-color: yellow' if v else '' for v in is_max]

display(
    HTML("""<p style="background-color:lightblue;color:black;font-weight: bold">
             each row - median highlight
         </p>""")
)

display(df.head(5).style.apply(highlight_max, axis=1))

display(
    HTML("""<p style="background-color:lightblue;color:black;font-weight: bold">
             each col - median highlight
         </p>""")
)
display(df.head(5).style.apply(highlight_max, axis=0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, each column is considered seperately when applying a background gradient.

You can verify this in your top image by comparing "74" in column 0 and column 4.

To treat each row seperately, use `df.style.background_gradient(cmap='RdYlGn_r', axis=1)`.

**Additional Information:**

See below code to generate the following display that colors the background nicely.

- Whole Dataframe (axis=None)
- Look at Each Column (axis=0) **[Default]**
- Look at Each Row (axis=1)

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
from IPython.display import display
from IPython.display import clear_output
from IPython.display import HTML

dfstr = StringIO(u"""
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19
85  83  90  78  70  70  65  79  49  28  14  11  4   52  90  19  78  7   10  50
10  10  10  5   0   4   6   5   5   5   4   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
16  33  81  81  47  68  20  75  92  65  39  26  53  82  1000    57  4   53  45  18
10  10  10  5   0   4   6   5   30  30  30  2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
100 299 399 50  50  50  50  50  50  50  300 200 201 300 200 300 204 200 305 300
""")
df = pd.read_csv(dfstr, sep="\t")

# df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(random.choice([100, 1000]), random.choice([10, 100]), size=(5, 12)))
# df



display(
    HTML("""<br /><p style="background-color:lightblue;color:black;font-weight: bold">
             whole dataframe (axis=None) - look at whole data frame
         </p>""")
)
display(df.style.background_gradient(cmap='RdYlGn_r', axis=None))

display(
    HTML("""<br /><p style="background-color:lightblue;color:black;font-weight: bold">
             each column (axis=0). all rows. This is the Default.<br />


         </p>""")
)
display(df.style.background_gradient(cmap='RdYlGn_r', axis=0)) #default



display(
    HTML("""<br /><p style="background-color:lightblue;color:black;font-weight: bold">
             each row (axis=1). all columns. <br />

         </p>""")
)
display(df.style.background_gradient(cmap='RdYlGn_r', axis=1))
```